# If $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y|X =k \sim \text{Bin}(k,r)$, can we say that $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,pr)$?

Tags: conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

Question:

> There are $n$ flower buds in a garden, each of which opens (independently) with a probability $p$ and each of the blooms survive (independently) with a probability $r$. What's the distribution of the number of buds that survive as a flower?

Attempt:

Let $X$ be the number of buds that open and $Y$ be the number of flowers that survive. Then $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y|X =k \sim \text{Bin}(k,r)$. I think eventually we will get $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,pr)$, but I don't know how to get there.

$$P(Y = y) = \sum_{k=y}^{n} P(Y = y | X = k)P(X=k) = \sum_{k=y}^{n} {k \choose y}r^y(1-r)^{k-y}{n \choose k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = ?$$

Comment: Before someone points out to this [similar problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342599/a-question-on-probability-involving-binomial-distribution), I am looking to continue with my approach which is different from the one there.

Comment: Yes, this is described on Wikipedia here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Conditional_binomials and probably already in a question here.

Comment: Your problem is the same as in the question that you linked to. Just compare the following 'flower buds opening = eggs hatching' and 'blooms surviving = chick survives'.